# Require Logrhythm Trainer

Tags: security, cybersource, soc

I am looking for a Logrhythm trainer. Mentioned below is the scope for Logrhythm training program.

1. Device Integrations and log sourcing
2. Customer Parsers, Regular Expressions, Filtering etc to fine tune rules for better threat detection and minimizing false positives
3. Collectors Performance Tuning
4. General Best Practices of Logrhythm administration

We need 2 hours every Friday OR Saturday, first half between 12-2 India time for 5-8 sessions

Feel free to connect at sayantani.mitra@skill-mine.com